# ActiveRecord Create ignores value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am doing this

```
CasPgtiou.create({:pgt_iou => "a", :pgt_id => "b"})
```

which results in

```
    INSERT INTO `cas_pgtious` (`created_at`, `pgt_id`, `pgt_iou`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-25 02:22:55', NULL, NULL, '2015-06-25 02:22:55')
            Mysql2::Error: Column 'pgt_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `cas_pgtious` (`created_at`, `pgt_id`, `pgt_iou`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-25 02:22:55', NULL, NULL, '2015-06-25 02:22:55')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'pgt_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `cas_pgtious` (`created_at`, `pgt_id`, `pgt_iou`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-06-25 02:22:55', NULL, NULL, '2015-06-25 02:22:55')
```

Even though the value is there the create function is not taking it.
Also the model I have is like this

```
class CasPgtiou < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :pgt_iou, :pgt_id
end
```

Rails version is 3.1.3. I'm not sure why a thing as simple as this would fail.

PS I have tried create this way also. But same error

> CasPgtiou.create(:pgt_iou => "a", :pgt_id => "b")

**UPDATE**

This thing strangely works

```
pgtiou = CasPgtiou.new
          pgtiou[:pgt_iou] = pgt_iou
          pgtiou[:pgt_id] = pgt
          pgtiou.save!
```

Comment: What type is :pgt_id in your schema?  Also, I can't think of a good reason to explicitly set `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes - you should let the database do that for you automatically.

Comment: Remove the space between the create call and the argument list.

Comment: I must have copied wrongly but it is not there in the original call

Comment: And you have definitely run migrations in this environment `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes I have run all of them. Also if I create it with new and set appropriate values and then save! it gives the same errror

Comment: I would try `CasPgtiou.create(pgt_iou: "a", pgt_id: "b")`

Comment: same error. I think I am missing some basic thing

Comment: OK one last suggestion - use `create!` to force validation errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81469/discussion-between-bali-and-steve-klein).